# Redux Dev Tools for React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, redux-toolkit

I'm building a React Native Expo app with redux toolkit for state management. I'm using Linux and Firefox. How can I debug using Redux DevTools when I use the Android emulator?

for now Im using the react native web so I can see the state and debug,

but I want to run only on the emulator

tried connecting the app to redux extension